# Can't access file because it is used in another process

Tags: c#

Compiler is giving me this:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I think the `File.WriteAllBytes` is the problem.

Code:

```
    File.Move(currentDir, @"uncompressed/" + filename);
    string fileName2 = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "tempfile.exe");
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName2, SC_Editor.Properties.Resources.ucsgflzma);
    string arguments = "uncompressed decompressed *.* -d";
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName2, arguments)
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };
    Process process = Process.Start(psi);
    getPngs();
}
else
{
    label2.Visible = false;
    label3.Visible = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Uhm, that's not an .sc file..", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

```
private void getPngs()
{
    label7.Text = "Getting .png's...";
    string fileName3 = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "tempfile.exe");
    string arguments2 = @"decompressed pngs *.*";
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName3, SC_Editor.Properties.Resources.ucssc);
    ProcessStartInfo psi2 = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName3, arguments2)
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };
    Process process = Process.Start(psi2);
}
```

Comment: Is the compiler giving that error? Or when you run the program? In the latter case you know excactly which call throws that exception.

Comment: When i run the program, it stucks at  File.WriteAllBytes(fileName3, SC_Editor.Properties.Resources.ucssc);

Comment: Well, no wonder, you created that same file earlier in filename2, and used that to start a Process. The exe file is locked in that case... your logic works as designed.

Comment: How can i fix that :D?

Comment: `string fileName3 = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "completelydifferentfilenamesoitwontcollidewithearlierfilenamesicreatedmyself.exe");`

Comment: Thanks :) Working now.

Comment: @TheCoder23 you can make your question more useful for future readers (and earn some reputation points) by following [Help Center > Answering > Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)